# how to display a multiple choice picker

Tags: ios7

i'm trying to find the correct control to display a choice selector, like the one which appears in Safari when you long press on image.

[image: Menu i would like to display]

It should be some kind of UIPickerView, but it is not the same design.

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by long press in Safari but the screenshot looks like UIActionSheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like UIActionSheet, which can be presented for example from the UITabBarController likes this:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"This will delete all your records. Are you sure you want to continue?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yes, go ahead." otherButtonTitles: nil];
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```